# SQL - join three tables based on (different) latest dates in two of them

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, left-join, oracle-sqldeveloper

Using Oracle SQL Developer, I have three tables with some common data that I need to join.
Appreciate any help on this!
Please refer to https://i.stack.imgur.com/f37Jh.png for the input and desired output (table formatting doesn't work on all tables).
These tables are made up in order to anonymize them, and in reality contain other data with millions of entries, but you could think of them as representing:

- Product = Main product categories in a grocery store.
- Subproduct = Subcategory products to the above. Each time the table is updated, the main product category may loses or get some new suproducts assigned to it. E.g. you can see that from May to June the Pulled pork entered while the Fishsoup was thrown out.
- Issues = Status of the products, for example an apple is bad if it has brown spots on it..

**What I need to find is:** for each P_NAME, find the latest updated set of subproducts (SP_ID and SP_NAME), and append that information with the latest updated issue status (STATUS_FLAG).
Please note that each main product category gets its set of subproducts updated at individual occasions i.e. 1234 and 5678 might be "latest updated" on different dates.

I have tried multiple queries but failed each time. I am using combos of `SELECT`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `JOIN`, `MAX` and `GROUP BY`.

Latest attempt, which gives me the combo of the first two tables, but missing the third:

```
SELECT
 PRODUCT.P_NAME,
 SUBPRODUCT.SP_PRODUCT_ID, SUBPRODUCT.SP_NAME, SUBPRODUCT.SP_ID, SUPPRODUCT.SP_VALUE_DATE
 FROM SUBPRODUCT
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCT ON PRODUCT.P_ID = SUBPRODUCT.SP_PRODUCT_ID
   JOIN(SELECT SP_PRODUCT_ID, MAX(SP_VALUE_DATE) AS latestdate FROM SUBPRODUCT GROUP BY SP_PRODUCT_ID) sub ON
sub.SP_PRODUCT_ID = SUBPRODUCT.SP_PRODUCT_ID AND sub.latestDate = SUBPRODUCT.SP_VALUE_DATE;
```

Comment: Side note, please don't use images - just copy/paste the table info into your question. We can always fix the formatting if needed.

Comment: @kfinity Thanks, I know and apologize for that. I tried formatting my four tables but only one of them were formatted so the rest looked like a mess in here. But yeah, good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to find a row with a max value is a common SQL pattern - you can do it with a join, like your example, but it's usually more clear to use a subquery or a window function.

Correlated subquery example

```
select 
  PRODUCT.P_NAME,
  SUBPRODUCT.SP_PRODUCT_ID, SUBPRODUCT.SP_NAME, SUBPRODUCT.SP_ID, SUPPRODUCT.SP_VALUE_DATE,
  ISSUES.STATUS_FLAG, ISSUES.STATUS_LAST_UPDATED
from PRODUCT
join SUBPRODUCT
  on PRODUCT.P_ID = SUBPRODUCT.SP_PRODUCT_ID
  and SUBPRODUCT.SP_VALUE_DATE = (select max(S2.SP_VALUE_DATE) as latestDate
                                  from SUBPRODUCT S2
                                  where S2.SP_PRODUCT_ID = SUBPRODUCT.SP_PRODUCT_ID)
join ISSUES
  on ISSUES.ISSUE_ID = SUBPRODUCT.SP_ID
  and ISSUES.STATUS_LAST_UPDATED = (select max(I2.STATUS_LAST_UPDATED) as latestDate
                                  from ISSUES I2
                                  where I2.ISSUE_ID = ISSUES.ISSUE_ID)
```

Window function / inline view example

```
select 
  PRODUCT.P_NAME,
  S.SP_PRODUCT_ID, S.SP_NAME, S.SP_ID, S.SP_VALUE_DATE,
  I.STATUS_FLAG, I.STATUS_LAST_UPDATED
from PRODUCT
join (select SUBPRODUCT.*, 
             max(SP_VALUE_DATE) over (partition by SP_PRODUCT_ID) as latestDate 
             from SUBPRODUCT) S
  on PRODUCT.P_ID = S.SP_PRODUCT_ID
  and S.SP_VALUE_DATE = S.latestDate
join (select ISSUES.*, 
             max(STATUS_LAST_UPDATED) over (partition by ISSUE_ID) as latestDate 
             from ISSUES) I
  on I.ISSUE_ID = S.SP_ID
  and I.STATUS_LAST_UPDATED = I.latestDate
```

This often performs a bit better, but window functions can be tricky to understand.

Comment: I ended up using the first one of your queries but with a LEFT OUTER JOIN to also get subproducts that don't have any ISSUES data (I was missing that detail in my original question). Thanks a lot!